# JQuery Masonry combined w/ Infinite Scroll. Infinite Scroll doesn't retain CSS

Tags: jquery

I have combined the JQuery Masonry plug in with the Infinite Scroll Plug in and the "infinite scroll" blocks don't retain the CSS of the Masonry "blocks" (see url). I am confused as to why and how this can be remedied. Thank you.

http://helpknow.com/black/

Comment: Are you notifing masonry after infinitescroll has loade new content?

Comment: Oh, and make sure you do that after the images of new content are really loaded.

Comment: Check it out here: http://www.emotiland.com

Comment: I don't know how to notify it after. I will look at that site and hopefully it's innards will show me.

Answer (score 0):

Masonry loads and formats the DOM objects. Infinite Scroll then adds more elements to the DOM. You need to tell Masonry to then format these new items.